# Updating wp_postmeta from meta_keys and meta_values from another table having price and sku only

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2 on pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
SET pm.meta_value = 'price such as 45'
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_price'
AND pm2.meta_key = '_sku' 
AND pm2.meta_value = 'having sku such as barcode here to update the price above';
```

Now what I need is to update that with TEMP table created in the same database, having columns `_SKU`, `_Price`

I did try to do something traditional, but it seems it is kinda not working or not even executed.
I don't know I do I update bulk product

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2 on pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
SET pm.meta_value = 'temp._price'
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_price'
AND pm2.meta_key = '_sku' 
AND pm2.meta_value = 'temp._sku';
```

The database is showing error that it couldn't find the column after executing it, giving `error 1054 unknown column`. Maybe I'm missing something, or maybe I need to have for loop.
[image]